# How to set default value of an attribute from yml file

Tags: java

in my yml file

```
default:
 title:newBook
```

on my object class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class myObj{

//how to set default value of          this from my yml file
private String title;


}
```

Get the value from yml file and set it as default value for my book title attribute
Make title not null

Answer (score -1):

Create a YamL configuration file

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "default")
public class YamlConfig {
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

then modify ur myobj as

```
private static String defaultTitle;

private String title;

    @Autowired
    public MyObj(YamlConfig yamlConfig) {
        this.title = yamlConfig.getTitle();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title != null ? title : defaultTitle;
    }
```

Comment: You’re assuming the so-called YAML file is `application.yml`

Answer (score -1):

In order to inject values from property files, environment variables, system properties and etc [@Value annotation](https://gustavopeiretti.com/spring-boot-value-annotation/#:%7E:text=Introduction%20to%20%40Value%20in%20Spring,value%20without%20recompiling%20the%20code.) is used. Besides it should be used
within [type of component stereotype](https://gustavopeiretti.com/spring-boot-components-stereotypes/) so that values can be injected from external sources when Spring creates beans in its context.
If you declare it as a Component as following:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class myObj{

   @Value("${default.title}")
   private String title;
    
}
```

then you can use myObj by autowiring. If you just invoke getTitle() it returns default value from property file. To change the title one needs to set the value by calling setTitle("another title")

```
@SpringBootTest
public class InheritTest {

    @Autowired myObj obj;

    
    @Test
    void testDto(){

    assertEquals(testDto.getTitle(),"hello from prod");
    testDto.setTitle("another title");
    assertEquals(testDto.getTitle(),"another title");
        
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Suppose you're trying to read them not from application.yml but let's say test.yml then you can create a class which implements PropertySourceFactory:

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

and use it in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "default")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:test.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Data
public class YamlTestProperties {
    private String title;
}
```

---

```
@SpringBootTest
public class InheritTest {

   
    @Autowired myObj obj;

    @Autowired
    private YamlTestProperties yamlTestProperties;



    
    @Test
    void testRetrieveTitleFromApplicationYaml(){

    assertEquals(testDto.getTitle(),"hello from prod");
    testDto.setTitle("another title");
    assertEquals(testDto.getTitle(),"another title");
        
    }

    @Test
    void testRetrieveTitleFromCustomYaml(){
        assertEquals(yamlTestProperties.getTitle(),"newBook");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) using `Value` is discouraged in favor of `ConfigurationProperties`. 2) You’re assuming the so-called YAML file is `application.yml`